# Ошибка при запуске миграций

Tags: laravel

Запускаю миграции, чтобы создать новые таблицы. Создание миграций останавливается на когда-то созданной таблице, и мне выдает ошибку:

`` SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'categories' already exists (SQL: create table `categories` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `title` varchar(255) null, `slug` varchar(255) null, `parent_id` bigint unsigned null default '0', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci') ``

Я могу выборочно запустить миграцию, или как-то исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете выборочно запустить миграцию командой

```
php artisan migrate —-path database\migration\namemigration.php
```